# custom binary json in Python 3.3 compatible with UBJsonReader Libgdx

Tags: java, c++, python, json, binary

I am using Blender to export some custom properties or information to Libgdx, I want to use json both text file and binary, I know how to use json module but I am do not know how to export a binary json compatible with one in libgdx (Also cross-platform), after some research I found that struct and array module are good for this porpuses, but I am not able to load in libgdx, I am not expert in Python and specially binary formats, also in UBJsonWriter.h in flowing address
https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv/tree/master/src/json
there are some predefined value

```
#define UBJSON_TYPE_NULL        'Z'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_TRUE        'T'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_FALSE       'F'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_BYTE        'B'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_SHORT       'i'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_INT     'I'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_LONG        'L'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_FLOAT       'd'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_DOUBLE      'D'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_HUGE1       'h'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_HUGE4       'H'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_STRING1     's'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_STRING4     'S'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_NOOP        'N'
#define UBJSON_TYPE_END     'E'
```

however with a simple

```
f.write(struct.pack('>c', b"{"))
f.write(struct.pack('>c', b"}"))
```

like this is not any problem, but further I do not know, I want the binary work on pc and androids.
Thanks for any guides.

Comment: You could just use the [`simpleubjson` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpleubjson).

Comment: Well I really would like to use Python standard library, if possible, and some learning, however those address may become handy. I do not know is UBjson compatible with Libgdx one?

Comment: UBJSON is a standard; if it isn't compatible that'd be a bug.

Comment: I will check and test, however it would be much nicer to know how can i implement a simple binary myself(i am eager to know).

Comment: Then check out the [`simpleubjson` source code](https://code.google.com/p/simpleubjson/source/browse/simpleubjson/draft9.py).

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, yes, well how can I flag your comment as answer?

Comment: You cannot, but I posted an answer below if you wanted to accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use the [`simpleubjson` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpleubjson) instead. Like libgdx, it implements the [UBJSON standard](http://ubjson.org/), in Python.

If you are curious how it implements the binary format, the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/simpleubjson/source/browse/simpleubjson/draft9.py) is available on GitHub for you to study.